# Extra zeroes when writing structure to file in C

Tags: c, file, structure, fwrite

So I'm writing an RLE compressor, and basically, you take the runs of a file (the continuous strings of the same byte) and convert it to a packet. For example, if the file contains:
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xBB 0xBB 0xBB you would convert it into packets, containing a length and the data: It would turn out 0x04FF 0x03BB. You get the idea.

I use a structure to define the packet. (byte is a typedefd type for an unsigned 8 bit type)

```
typedef struct      /* Each packet has a length and a data byte */
{
    byte length;    /* how many elements of data there is */
    byte data;      /* whatever byte is being repeated */
} PACKET;
```

and I have my writeData function:

```
void writeData(FILE* f, int offset, PACKET p) 
{
    fseek(f,offset,SEEK_SET); /* move to the offset to write */
    fwrite(&p,sizeof(PACKET),sizeof(PACKET),f); /* write the packet to the given offset */
}
```

And here is the code that calls the function

```
    offsetCounter = 0x0;            /* reset offset counter */
    for(i = 0; i < nPackets; i++) /* nPackets is the total amount of packets created */
    {
        writeData(fDest,offsetCounter,packet[i]);
        printf("Wrote %d:0x%X to 0x%X\n",packet[i].length,packet[i].data,offsetCounter);
        offsetCounter += 0x02;      /* skip 2 bytes to write the next packet */
    }
```

When I run the program, everything works fine, and the packets are written to the file correctly, except for some reason, at the very end of the file, there are 2 0x00 bytes that are automatically added on. So, for some reason, it just adds 2 extra empty bytes.

***However,*** when I write the writeData function like this:

```
void writeData(FILE* f, int offset, PACKET p) 
{
    fseek(f,offset,SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&p.length,sizeof(byte),sizeof(byte),f);
    fwrite(&p.data,sizeof(byte),sizeof(byte),f);
}
```

, which writes each byte of the structure separately, it no longer adds 2 extra empty bytes to the end of the file..

I'm really confused as to why when I write the structure, it works fine, but adds 2 extra bytes at the end, but when I write each element of the structure separately, it doesn't add them.

Could somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: What hardware are you on? More specifically, what are the alignment/padding requirements for the hardware and the compiler?

Comment: Insert a `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(PACKET));` about anywhere and the result may surprise you.

Comment: @Jongware, the proper way to print a `size_t` is `%zu` (Note: windows is stuck at C89, so this won't work there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the incorrect line

```
fwrite(&p,sizeof(PACKET),sizeof(PACKET),f);
```

The structure size is 2 so you are writing 2 of them and this is where your two extra bytes are coming from. It should be

```
fwrite(&p,sizeof(PACKET),1,f);
```

The reason why the extra bytes only show up at the end of the file, is because you use `fseek()` to position the file pointer, which is incremented correctly by 2. NB. When you are writing sequentially to a file, you don't need to use `fseek()` anyway. Also, you have hard-coded with `offsetCounter += 0x02;` instead of using `offsetCounter += sizeof(PACKET)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I just realized I misinterpreted the reference page when it said "Number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes." For whatever reason I thought I had to put (size * amount) to be written. Thanks!